# BeautifulSoup: get text from some tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have data

```
<span class="label">Привод:</span> передний<br/>
<span class="label">Тип кузова:</span> седан<br/>
<span class="label">Цвет:</span> серый<br/>
<span class="label">Пробег по России:</span> есть<br/>
<span class="label">Пробег, км:</span> 87000<br/>
<span class="label">Руль:</span> левый<br/>
```

I need to get `87000`
I try

```
mileage = soup.find('span', class_='label', text='Пробег, км:').findNext('br').get_text()
```

or

```
mileage = soup.find('span', class_='label', text='Пробег, км:').next_subling
```

but it returns None.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you are trying to get the text of the `br` element but it does not have any.

In the second code snippet you have a typo - it is not `next_subling`, it is [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find('span', class_='label', text='Пробег, км:').next_sibling
```